# T-SQL temp data comparison # vs WITH

Tags: t-sql

I have been working with basic SQL for a couple years already.  However, only recently I encounter the "WITH" command.  From my research, it looks like "WITH" is a method to create a temporary table.  But in my experience, you can also use the hash "#" to create a temp table.

I tried to search "WITH" and "#", but since these are weird search words, I am not getting much result.

Could someone chime me in on what is the difference such as pros and cons for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `WITH` to create a Common Table Expression (CTE).  It is not technically a temp table.

A temp table is like any other table, but it is stored in `tempdb` and dropped when the connection is closed.

Unlike a temp table, though, a CTE doesn't actually have a physical store to it.  It's more like a "view".

[Here is a great article on exactly what CTEs are](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/18/ctes-common-table-expressions.aspx).  And unlike temp tables, that persist for the connection, a CTE is:

> defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement

[MSDN Reference on Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` is a table created on-the-fly (in memory), so it's potentially much faster than a temporary (#) table that is like any other table, but it's automatically dropped when you close the connection.  The con is that it's only alive for one statement